# How to compute: $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2 e^{\sin(1/x)}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Does anyone know how to compute the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^2 e^{\sin(1/x)}$$

My attempt is that this limit does not exist because the limit of $\sin(1/x)$ as $x$ tends to $0$ does not exist. Anyone has a good proof for this?

Comment: A good thing to do before starting (though not necessarily a proof) would be to use some software to graph the function.

Comment: @David That might be an idea for checking your answer, but I'm not sure about doing that beforehand. You might as well look up the answer on a calculator whilst you're at at.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I don't agree, the point is that a proof is still required.  You won't get that from the graph, or by looking up the answer on a calculator.

Comment: @David of course. But plotting the graph will tell you what the answer is, and part of this exercise is gaining the intuition to work that out for yourself.

Comment: @Mathmo123 No, plotting the graph will (may) **suggest** what the answer is, it will not tell you for sure.  And clearly the OP at this stage does not have the intuition to guess the right answer.  Hopefully they will learn to do so in the future, but what are they to do now if they have no examples to look at?  Is plotting the graph really any worse than asking on MSE?

Comment: @David when asking on math.SE, hopefully the people answering the question will answer in such a way as to explain to you why the result is true and how to get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
-ex^2 \le x^2 e^{\sin(1/x)} \le ex^2 \quad\text{ since }|e^{\sin(1/x)}|\le e.
$$
So what do $-ex^2$ and $ex^2$ approach as $x\to 0\text{ ?}$

Comment: Indeed, by the squeeze theorem, the limit goes to zero. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\big\vert \sin\left( \dfrac 1x\right)\big\vert \le 1$ for all $x$, and $e^x$ is monotonic, so $0<\mathrm e^{\sin( \frac 1x)}\le \mathrm e$.

Comment: That is one very good hint +1

Answer (score 3):

You have a function $e^{\sin(1/x)}$, that is not definded on $0$, even though, it is a bounded function since $e^{-1}\leq e^{\sin(1/x)} \leq e$ and you have that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 =0$ than $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2e^{\sin(1/x)} =0$, because 
$$x^2e^{-1}\leq x^2e^{\sin(1/x)} \leq x^2e$$ and 
$$lim_{x\to 0}x^2e^{-1}=\lim_{x\to 0} x^2e=0$$
use sandwich theorem.